# How can I get the all of the img src by using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

try to do in scrapy shell

```
>>>scrapy shell 'https://www.trendyol.com/trendyolmilla/cok-renkli-desenli-elbise-twoss20el0573-p-36294862'
>>> response.css("div.slick-slide img").xpath("@src").getall()
```

Output is :

```
['/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg', '/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg', '/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg', '/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg', '/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg', 'https://cdn.dsmcdn.com/mnresize/415/622/ty124/product/media/images/20210602/12/94964657/64589619/1/1_org_zoom.jpg', 'https://cdn.dsmcdn.com/mnresize/415/622/ty124/product/media/images/20210602/12/94964657/64589619/1/1_org_zoom.jpg']
```

only collect one image but in provided link have 5 image. Please help me to out this problem. How to find all of the image src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

Actually, you are trying to fetch the data from HTML tag which contains only one link. In order to grab all the link you have to fetch from script tag.

This will return json string which will be stored in text variable

```
text = response.xpath("//p/script[contains(@type,'application/ld+json')]/text()").extract_first()
```

Load it to convert into python dictionary

```
json_text = json.loads(text)
```

Now, pass the key `json_text.get('image')` to get the images.

**Code**

Execute this code on scrapy. Output will give you all the 5 links

```
from scrapy import Request


class Trendyol(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.trendyol.com/trendyolmilla/cok-renkli-desenli-elbise-twoss20el0573-p-36294862'
        yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        text = response.xpath("//p/script[contains(@type,'application/ld+json')]/text()").extract_first()
        json_text = json.loads(text)

        print(json_text.get('image'))
```

Comment: sir, i use this already its collect only one src file, i need all of them. if you see in the link there has 5 image. i want to collect all of them. in the output '/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg' this not a image, its only a text

Comment: @AliVaiExpress, I have modified my answer. please check it.

Comment: sir, im using python 2.7 and this code show invalid syntax, so i used response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, 'pd-img')]/img/@src')[position() >= 1 and position() < 6]
 this, its also show invalid in 'pd-img'.

Comment: @AliVaiExpress, the syntax error for first part is bcoz of not wrapping the path inside quotes. The error for your modified version is bcoz we have to use quotes (single or double quotes) together in the same string, in such cases, we use single and double quotes alternatively so that they can be distinguished like this response.xpath('(//div[contains(@class, "pd-img")]/img/@src)[position() >= 1 and position() < 6]').getall()

Comment: sir, now ok but i didnt find my desired output. output is ['/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg', '/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg', '/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg', '/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg', '/Content/images/defaultThumb.jpg']
these are not image or image src. if you check my output given in the question these showed a image src link.

Comment: @AliVaiExpress, use the above code & let me know if you get desired results. After, your confirmation, I will add the explaination.

Comment: thank you sir, it's ok. and that's great. many many thanks again.i learn many things from you

Comment: sir, please explain this path (("//p/script[contains(@type,'application/ld+json')]/text()")) i didn't understand anything in this path. but this code work great.

Comment: sir, now i understand. i check in the source page and find this javascript in a p tag.

Comment: @AliVaiExpress, that's great you got it. I will add the complete explanation by the end of the day so that it can help others. Feel free to upvote the answer if you think it helped you.

Comment: yes, its help me. but i can't upvote this ans. i have not enough reputation. after reaching 15 reputation i vote this.

Comment: @AliVaiExpress, No problem, Keep learning. By the way, I have added the explanation.

Comment: sir i need your help once again.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181160/how-to-collect-all-of-the-ancor-href-using-scrapy

Comment: sir help me once again, please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230846/hoe-fetch-all-data-and-parse-using-meta-in-scrapy

Comment: sir this solution gives me an error and is : TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType. what can i do now?