# How fetch all data and parse using meta in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to save all of the data in a json file.
how can i parse my data using meta?
I don't know my meta format is ok or not.
finally yield the all of the data (which i through by meta and which i parse_v) in a json file
help me to out this problem, please.

now i add full code. hope so you find out my problem

```
import json
import scrapy
import time
import chompjs
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class TrendyolSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'data'
    start_urls = ['https://www.trendyol.com/join-us/straplez-firfirli-simli-astarli-triko-elbise-krem-p-41896200']


    def final_parse(self, response):
        abc = response.xpath("//p/script[contains(@type,'application/ld+json')]/text()").extract_first()
        json_text = json.loads(abc)
        img = json_text.get('image')

        products = response.css('div.pd-app-container')
        for product in products:
            category = product.css('div.breadcrumb>a:nth-child(3)+ a.breadcrumb-item span::text').get(),
            product_name = product.css("h1.pr-new-br ::text").getall(),
            price = product.css('div.pr-bx-nm  span.prc-org::text').get().replace("TL", ""),
            discount_price = product.css('div.pr-bx-nm  span.prc-slg::text').get().replace("TL", ""),
            brand = response.css("div.sl-nm a::text").get(),
            image = img,
            size = product.css("div.pr-in-at-sp ::text").getall(),
            product_information = product.css("div.pr-in-dt-cn ::text").getall(),
            product_features = product.css("div.pr-prop-content ::text").getall(),


        all_info = response.xpath("//script[contains(@type,'application/javascript')]/text()").extract_first()
        product_json = chompjs.parse_js_object(all_info)
        ides = product_json['product']['productGroupId']

        varient_url = "https://public.trendyol.com/discovery-web-productgw-service/api/productGroup/" + str(ides)

        yield Request(url=varient_url, callback=self.parse_v, meta={
            'category': category,
            'product_name': product_name,
            'price': price,
            'discount_price': discount_price,
            'brand': brand,
            'image': image,
            'size': size,
            'product_information': product_information,
            'product_features': product_features,
        })

    def parse_v(self, response):
        json_tex5 = json.loads(response.body)
        dataa = json_tex5.get('result').get("slicingAttributes")[0].get("attributes")
        yield {
            'category': response.meta['category'],
            'product_name': response.meta['product_name'],
            'price': response.meta['price'],
            'discount_price': response.meta['discount_price'],
            'brand': response.meta['brand'],
            'image': response.meta['image'],
            'size': response.meta['size'],
            'product_information': response.meta['product_information'],
            'product_features': response.meta['product_features'],
            'renk': dataa
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer according to your question:

If you want to transfer data from one parse methon to another using meta, you need to create key for each value and injected each key-value pair in Request using meta
,after all, in parse_v method, you have to create key newly and to grab previous key using response.meta and it's the new key-value pairs to yield data like 'Category': response.meta['cat']

```
class TrendyolSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'data'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.trendyol.com/olalook/kadin-siyah-cepli-minik-beyaz-cicekli-klos-elbise-elb-19000480-p-6635101']

    def parse(self, response):
        text = response.xpath(
            "//p/script[contains(@type,'application/ld+json')]/text()").extract_first()
        json_text = json.loads(text)
        items = TrendyolItem()
        products = response.css('div.pd-app-container')
        for product in products:
            category = product.css(
                'div.breadcrumb>a:nth-child(3)+ a.breadcrumb-item span::text').get(),
            product_name = product.css('div.pr-in-cn h1.pr-new-br::text').get() + " " + product.css(
                'div.pr-in-cn h1.pr-new-br span::text').get(),
            price = product.css(
                'div.pr-bx-nm  span.prc-org::text').get().replace("TL", ""),
            discount_price = product.css(
                'div.pr-bx-nm  span.prc-slg::text').get().replace("TL", ""),
            brand = response.css("div.sl-nm a::text").get(),
            image = json_text.get('image'),
            size = product.css("div.pr-in-at-sp ::text").getall(),
            product_information = product.css(
                "div.pr-in-dt-cn ::text").getall(),
            product_features = product.css(
                "div.pr-prop-content ::text").getall(),

            items['category'] = category
            items['product_name'] = product_name
            items['price'] = price
            items['discount_price'] = discount_price
            items['brand'] = brand
            items['image'] = image
            items['size'] = size
            items['product_information'] = product_information
            items['product_features'] = product_features

        all_info = response.xpath(
            "//script[contains(@type,'application/javascript')]/text()").extract_first()
        product_json = chompjs.parse_js_object(all_info)
        ides = product_json['product']['productGroupId']

        varient_url = "https://public.trendyol.com/discovery-web-productgw-service/api/productGroup/" + \
            str(ides)

        yield Request(
            url=varient_url,
            callback=self.parse_v,
            meta={'cat': category, 'pro_name': product_name,'p': price, 'dis_price': discount_price,
            'bra': brand,'ima':image,'si':size, 'porduct_info':product_information,'features':product_features
            }
            )

    def parse_v(self, response):
        #items = response.meta['items']
        json_tex5 = json.loads(response.body)
        dataa = json_tex5.get('result').get(
            "slicingAttributes")[0].get("attributes")
        for i in dataa:
            all_info = self.start_urls + i['contents'][0]['url'] + "https://cdn.dsmcdn.com"+i['contents'][0]['imageUrl']\
                + i['contents'][0]['price']['discountedPrice']['text'] + \
                i['contents'][0]['price']['originalPrice']['text']

        yield {
            'Category': response.meta['cat'],
            'Product_name': response.meta['pro_name'],
            'Price': response.meta['p'],
            'Discount_price': response.meta['dis_price'],
            'Brand': response.meta['bra'],
            'Image': response.meta['ima'],
            'Size': response.meta['si'],
            'Product_information': response.meta['porduct_info'],
            'Product_features': response.meta['features'],
            'rank': all_info
        }
```

Comment: thank you, but i found only one data from all_info, but in link have more data.

Comment: and if i used this link https://public.trendyol.com/discovery-web-productgw-service/api/productGroup/73959883 show IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Actually, your  question  was to solve meta problem which is  correct here . You may mix up your data generating with both type of response meaning font-end with backdoor in incorrect way .

Comment: yes, you solve meta problem, but in my question i mentioned i need all data. if i used this link in starts_url then i find list index out of range. https://www.trendyol.com/fox-fitness/f70-katlanabilir-dijital-gostergeli-el-ayak-egzersiz-p-62361347

Comment: I'm getting the following exception:   product_name = product.css('div.pr-in-cn h1.pr-new-br::text').get() + " " + product.css(        
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: sir, i add this new starts_url because sometimes i found some link like that in website.

Comment: now getting : product_json = chompjs.parse_js_object(all_info)
NameError: name 'chompjs' is not defined

Comment: sorry sir, i edited again. please check once again

Comment: Try yourself  or you can give me detailed  requirements then I will try to solve my own way.

Comment: sir now check, i add full code. you find main problem easily.

Comment: sorry, i can't install chompjs in my system right now

Comment: it's ok sir, just tell me one think. dataa = json_tex5.get('result').get(
            "slicingAttributes")[0].get("attributes")  in this line i find data when have data in varient_url. if varient_url is empty show an error IndexError: list index out of range. how can i solve it? i used if and else but didnt work.

Comment: you can apply here try except statement. Thanks

Comment: The site is using api for it's first portion and product reviews and product feactures psrts are fully controlled by javaScript that's why if you want to get full information ,the perfect solution is Selenium with scrapy.